# Use /dev/input/mice to generate a RSA key in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, public-key-encryption

Here's my code so far. What I want to do is generate an RSA key based on the user's mouse movements.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def rand(leng):
    data = open("/dev/input/mice","rb").read(leng)
    return data

key = RSA.generate(1024,rand)
print(key.exportKey())
```

The issue I'm having is that the program just freezes. The error seems to be in reading /dev/input/mice from inside a function. If I try reading it in python from anywhere else, it works as expected.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Don't do it.  Use a standard source of entropy.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I know it's a bad idea, but I want to try it.